# scipy does not load correctly in pycharm

Tags: python, scipy, pycharm, anaconda

I have imported **scipy** by this command in **pycharm**:

```
import scipy as sp
```

but as I want to use it in this way for example:

```
a=sp.special.factorial(5)
```

I receive an error related to module attribute and I have to import **scipy** in below way only, to get no error:

```
from scipy import special
```

but in another IDE like **Spyder** both commands runs with no error.
I use **anaconda** as interpretor in **pycharm**.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Spyder. Perhaps they did something extra. But the official way of doing is you have to `import scipy.special` serapately.

```
import scipy
help(scipy)  # it will give the following help message.
```

Help on package scipy:

NAME
    scipy

DESCRIPTION
    SciPy: A scientific computing package for Python
    ================================================

```
Documentation is available in the docstrings and
online at http://docs.scipy.org.

Contents
--------
SciPy imports all the functions from the NumPy namespace, and in
addition provides:

Subpackages
-----------
Using any of these subpackages requires an explicit import.  For example,
``import scipy.cluster``.
```